# how to enable php curl for use in php cli

Tags: php

I've installed php on my computer without a server and running it using cli php curl isn't enabled and I don't have a clue how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - [How use cURL library when running PHP through Command Line](http://www.akchauhan.com/how-use-curl-library-when-running-php-through-command-line/)

---

you need first to install cURL

> - http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html
> - [http://it.php.net/features.commandline [via Web Archive]](https://web.archive.org/web/20140818194613/http://it.php.net/features.commandline)

Answer (score 2):

In case someone comes across this thread and uses wamp server, here's a quick fix for the problem above http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,47455