# Run PHP file which contains curl

Tags: php, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to enable php curl for use in php cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675070/how-to-enable-php-curl-for-use-in-php-cli)

I am running a file which containing curl function. When i run in command prompt i am getting below error.

test.php

```
<?php
echo "Hai";

$url="http://www.google.com/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$str = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $str;
?>
```

Command : **C:\>test>php test.php**

Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init()

When i run in web browser its running fine.

Information i got

```
<?php
dl("php_curl.dll");
...
?>
```

Not solved still

Comment: PHP often uses a different php.ini for the web server and for the CLI.  You probably have to enable the cURL extension in the CLI's php.ini.  Find out where it is with `php -i`.

Comment: The linked CV duplicate is a link-only answer to an external site. Don't close against that question. (The first one is not always the best one!)

Comment: I searched a lot but did not get the question. Problem not solved with that questions thnks - @Lix

Comment: @Lix : Could you try and post the exact answer. There the problem is not solved.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : Hey, i enabled **cURL extension**. Working fine in web browser but not in CLI

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have different configuration for web servers and cli...
Try checking if there is more php.ini files in your filesystem

Answer (score 1):

This will happen when the curl extension is not enabled for command line PHP.

Check whether it is enabled or not in the `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file

This is the specific `php.ini` file for command line PHP.

Comment: is there any command to run like this $>php curl test.php

Comment: You just have to enable the curl extension in the php.ini for cli. Once you enable it, the PHP script should work even from command line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that curl has not been installed as your PHP extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need the cURL library in order to run cURL commands from the command prompt. Try using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), or download the cURL executable. You can find it here: http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin